# Chrome won't quit after assertion error occurs

Tags: java, selenium

I'm trying to get the browser to close when the test fails via assertion.

It outputs the correct log info in the log, but the browser does not close.

java.lang.AssertionError: Error: Title is 'Jordan | TolaActivity', and should be Country Name | TolaActivity

```
at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)
at org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:41)
at Tola.Activity.tests.LoginPage.Login(LoginPage.java:61)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at
```

```
    @Test
    // Test Case # 1: User can login successfuly
    //

    public void Login() throws Exception {
        // -- Setup
        driver.get(constants.URL);
        Assert.assertTrue("Error: Title is '" + driver.getTitle() + "', and should be company name Sign-on", driver.getTitle().startsWith("company name"));

        // -- Test

        driver.findElement(By.id("login")).sendKeys("username");

        driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("password");

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"loginbox\"]/center[2]/input")).click();

        Assert.assertTrue("Error: Title is '" + driver.getTitle() + "', and should be Country Name | TolaActivity", driver.getTitle().contains("asdasd"));

        driver.quit();
    }

}
```

Comment: If `assertTrue` throws an exception then `driver.quit()` won't be called. You could use a try-finally block, but since you're using JUnit you could also use before/after methods.

Comment: Im not the most experienced developer, could you provide an example using my code? I've tried a catch, successfuly closes the browser but it says the test passed, even though the assertion was actually not true

Comment: As this is dealing with unit testing, there's no reason to have a catch. Just use try-finally: `try { /* test code */ } finally { driver.quit(); }`. If, however, you _do_ need a catch as well, simply re-throw the exception. And depending on your use case, you might want to consider using ["test fixtures"](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/Test-fixtures) (← link points to JUnit 4, if you ever upgrade to JUnit 5, see the [user guide](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/)).

Answer (score 2):

You need to utilize some sort of error handling. An exception is being thrown from your assert and is not being handled, so your following quit is never called. Here is one example - Depending on your project structure you might want to do it higher up in your call hierarchy.

```
   public void Login() throws Exception {

try {
        // -- Setup
        driver.get(constants.URL);
        Assert.assertTrue("Error: Title is '" + driver.getTitle() + "', and should be Mercy Crops Sign-on", driver.getTitle().startsWith("Mercy Corps"));

        // -- Test

        driver.findElement(By.id("login")).sendKeys("username");

        driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("password");

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"loginbox\"]/center[2]/input")).click();

        Assert.assertTrue("Error: Title is '" + driver.getTitle() + "', and should be Country Name | TolaActivity", driver.getTitle().contains("asdasd"));
}
catch(/*Your assert exception */) {
         ///Handle an error here if you want to do something more 
}
finally {
        driver.quit();
}
}
```

Comment: When i try it this way, the assertion fails but it still "passes" the test?

Comment: In that case you have to re-`throw` the exception inside the `catch` clause to make it fail.

Answer (score 1):

Create a method that gets run after your test method which will quit the driver.  This will close your driver after everything in your test method has run.

```
@After
public void teardown() { 
  this.driver.quit()
}
```

Comment: Since `Assert.assertTrue("value");` statement has specific meaning which you should not handle, better use `@AfterMethod(alwaysRun = true)` to quit the browser